# Nested modules and instance level methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, instance

Suppose I have

```
module A
  include module B

  class C
    def methodC
      B.methodB
    end
    def self.methodD 
      somemethod
    end
  end
end

module B
  def self.methodB
    A::C.methodD
  end    
end

instance = A::C.new
```

How can I avoid using the use of this class level methods (self) ? In fact, how could I call `methodB` on `instance` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood, the keyword to call the current instance inside some method is `self`. So you can use

```
def methodC
     self.methodB
end
```

and delete `self` inside `self.methodB`.

(Btw, unless `methodD` has to figure inside `class C`, you can put it inside `moduleB` and then delete the `A::C` for `methodD` ;))

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
# define moduke B first so that, it can be included in A
module B
  def methodB
    A::C.methodD
  end
end

module A

  class C
    include B # include B here  

    def methodC
      methodB
    end

    def self.methodD 
      somemethod
    end
  end
end

instance = A::C.new
p instance.methods.grep /methodB/
=> [:methodB]
```